# Shopify create products to sell by weight

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

How can I create a product type that can be sold by weight? Like cheese by the gram? I am very new to Shopify but fairly experience in coding in general.

Comment: what do you want exactly for the customer ? For example choosing 123g ?

Comment: Would it work in your instance to set the unit price be for 1g of cheese and use the quantity box to be the weight field?  To compliment that, you could set up an alternate template for 'by-the-gram' where the quantity box has an initial value of something reasonable, like 500 (g), or you could replace the number field with a select drop-down where the option values are reasonable quantities that you sell by...